# unable to get table from postgreSQL despite the spring boot program being connected to database and the database not being empty

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I am rather new to Spring boot and I am trying to write a very simple program that can perform post, get and delete on a postgreSQL data base. the database is named "recipes" schema "public" and table "recipe"
The problem that I ran into is that when I make the get request through postman, it simply returns null despite the data base being initialized with data.

like so
[image]

I did my best to try and narrow down the problem and the furthest I got is that line from the service layer is returning nothing when evaluated

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RecipeRowMapper())
```

The database is initialized with the following SQL

```
INSERT INTO recipe(id, name, ingredients, instructions, date_added)
values (1, 'ini test1', '10 cows 20 rabbits', 'cook ingredients with salt', '2004-01-02'),
       (2, 'ini test2', '30 apples 20 pears', 'peel then boil', '2004-01-13');
```

I know the database is not empty because when I run the following SQL

```
SELECT * from recipe
```

i get

[image]

And the data base is connected as seen below (one thing I do find strange is that the table "recipe" isn't showing up in the DB browser but I don't know what to make of it)

[image]

application.yml

```
app:
  datasource:
    main:
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/recipes?currentSchema=public
      username: postgres
      password: password

server:
  error:
    include-binding-errors: always
    include-message: always

spring.jpa:
  database: POSTGRESQL
  hibernate.ddl-auto: create
  show-sql: true
  dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
  format_sql: true

spring.flyway:
  baseline-on-migrate: true
```

this is the service layer

```
    public List<Recipe> getRecipes(){
        var sql = """
            SELECT id, name, ingredients, instructions, date_added
            FROM public.recipe
            LIMIT 50
            """;
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RecipeRowMapper());
    }
```

and this is the controller

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/test")
    public String testRecipe(){
        return recipeService.test();
    }
```

and rowmapper

```
public class RecipeRowMapper implements RowMapper<Recipe> {
    @Override
    public Recipe mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return new Recipe(
                rs.getLong("id"),
                rs.getString("name"),
                rs.getString("ingredients"),
                rs.getString("instructions"),
                LocalDate.parse(rs.getString("date_added"))
        );
    }
}
```

finally recipe entity looks like this

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "ingredients")
    private String ingredients;
    @Column(name = "instructions")
    private String instructions;
    @Column(name = "date_added")
    private LocalDate dateAdded;

    public Recipe(){};
    public Recipe(long id, String name, String ingredients, String instructions, LocalDate date){}

    public Recipe(String name,
                  String ingredients,
                  String instructions,
                  LocalDate dateAdded
                  ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
        this.instructions = instructions;
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the problem is caused by the LocalDate not being converted correctly and was being posted as null. That caused the

```
 LocalDate.parse(rs.getString("date_added"))
```

to throw a null pointer exception which is what has been causing all the problems...